# MongoDB - Get a summary of the count for each field for each value of a collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I would like to get a summary of the count for each field for each value of a collection.

**Example:**

A collection may contain the following document schema and values:

```
{
    shop: A, B, C, D
    fruits: banana, apple, kiwi
    region: north, south, west, east
}
```

**Goal:**
I want to get a single document as a result with the count for every value like this:

```
{
    shop: {
        A: 2,
        B: 5,
        C: 3,
        D: 1
    },
    fruits: {
        banana: 3,
        apple: 2,
        kiwi: 1
    }
    ...
}
```

How is that possible with mongo?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$facet` to separate result for all three fields
- `$project` `shop` field only
- `$unwind` deconstruct `shop` array
- `$group` by `shop` and get count
- `$project` to show only key as `shop` and value as `count`
- same process both other 2 arrays `fruits` and `region`
- `$arrayToObject` convert key-value array to object format

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      shop: [
        { $project: { shop: 1 } },
        { $unwind: "$shop" },
        { $group: { _id: "$shop", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
        { $project: { _id: 0, k: "$_id", v: "$count" } }
      ],
      fruits: [
        { $project: { fruits: 1 } },
        { $unwind: "$fruits" },
        { $group: { _id: "$fruits", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
        { $project: { _id: 0, k: "$_id", v: "$count" } }
      ],
      region: [
        { $project: { region: 1 } },
        { $unwind: "$region" },
        { $group: { _id: "$region", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
        { $project: { _id: 0, k: "$_id", v: "$count" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      shop: { $arrayToObject: "$shop" },
      fruits: { $arrayToObject: "$fruits" },
      region: { $arrayToObject: "$region" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d6G4MjyfWOu)